# 404 для файлов

Tags: http-status-code-404, php

Рисунки на сайте отдает скрипт. (Или не отдает).
Как правильно отшить неверный запрос, если рисунка нет?
Достаточно ли просто отправить 404 заголовок?

Comment: Можно слать дефолтную картинку 100x100 с надписью "no image"

Comment: Ну, можно, конечно, но это не совсем то, что я бы хотел. 
Просто рисунок, которого нет возвращает

    HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    Date: Sun, 18 Nov 2012 13:07:42 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5
    Content-Length: 205
    Server: Apache

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>404 Not Found</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>
    <p>The requested URL /dfg.jpg was not found on this server.</p>
    </body></html>

То есть, фактически, он возвращает другой майм даже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В заголовках отправлять код 404, mime-type: image/jpg, а тело ответа - картинка с надписью "Image not found". Картинка должна быть в формате jpeg, соответственно.

Тогда и в браузере будет красиво, и вроде как, по стандарту, при получении кода 404 нормальные программы обычно понимают, что запрашиваемый ресурс не найден)

Answer (score -1):

`file_exists($urlpic)` возвращает логическое true или false, если файл $urlpic есть, или его нет соответственно.